# How to fix running failed in react-native for Android (Mac machine)?

Tags: java, android, ssl, react-native

**I tried to run react native Application in the Android emulator. but the terminal throwing the error and exit the process.**

But It's working fine in the iOS simulator.

Already have my android sdk installed and I also have java installed.

this is what is in my .bach_profile,

```
export JAVA_HOME=$Home/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

I'm getting this error,

```
Installing the app...
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:67)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:52)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:450)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:317)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:445)
        ... 26 more

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:67)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:52)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:62)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:450)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:317)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237)
```

Sombody please explain this error and help me to resolve this.

Comment: can you try to run this --- 

source $HOME/.bash_profile

before running 
npx react-native run-android

Comment: You mean run the command like this in terminal @AnwarGul
`> source $HOME/.bash_profile `

Comment: yes run it in the terminal

Comment: did but getting the same error